# What is wrong with int() function not accepting string in Python?

Tags: python, string, int

I am relatively new to programming and I would like to test the base conversion ability of the int() function.
When I write:

```
>>> int("3",2)
11
```

it displays this. However, if I use:

```
>>> int('3',2)
```

it displays a value error, invalid literal for int with base 2: '3'
What is going on? This does not allow me to use int(str(a),2) for example.
I'm using Python 3.7.0 if this helps. I'm very frustrated with this problem.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with passing `2` as the second parameter?

Comment: single and double quotes are interchangeable for strings in python. When I run your first example, I see the error message you are describing -- not 11.

Comment: It's the numeral system base. It converts number 3 to 11 in binary.

Comment: Hello HiTek, and welcome to the site.  I'm unable to reproduce your problem, see here: http://rextester.com/XEDOQO96274

Comment: @MoxieBall I don't understand, the first example does work to me.

Comment: Have you imported any modules into the shell/script that is running from, or defined any functions? can you `print(locals())` before running `int("3",2)`?

Comment: It is very unlikely that `int("3",2)` returned 11.

Comment: Wait, you're right, I messed up the question. I'll delete it.

Answer (score 2):

The error message `invalid literal for int() with base 2: '3'` tells you what is wrong: In [base 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number), the only valid digits are `0` and `1`. If you're trying to parse a string in base 2, `3` is an invalid digit.

If you want a binary string from an integer string, you can use one of the the following:

```
>>> bin(int("3"))
'0b11'
>>> bin(int("3"))[2:]
'11'
>>> "{0:b}".format(int("3"))
'11'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int):

> if base is given, then x must be a string, bytes, or bytearray
>   instance representing an integer literal in radix base

So you need to supply a string representing an integer in base 2 with this call, i.e. a string with only `"0"` or `"1"`.